# The log no longer has [Parachain] and [RelayChain] tags

Tags: log

this is the normal log:
[image]
When I upgraded to version 22, the log was missing the tags:
[image]
and there is no problem with the code for `sc_tracing`:

```
/// Start a node with the given parachain `Configuration` and relay chain `Configuration`.
///
/// This is the actual implementation that is abstract over the executor and the runtime api.
#[sc_tracing::logging::prefix_logs_with("Parachain")]
async fn start_node_impl<RuntimeApi, Executor, RB, BIQ, BIC>(
    parachain_config: Configuration,
    polkadot_config: Configuration,
    collator_options: CollatorOptions,
    id: ParaId,
    _rpc_ext_builder: RB,
    build_import_queue: BIQ,
    build_consensus: BIC,
    hwbench: Option<sc_sysinfo::HwBench>,
) -> sc_service::error::Result<(
```

Comment: Oh dear. I was hoping those tags would migrate to becoming emojis so they were still there but only took up 1 char.

Comment: What argument flags are you using to boot up this node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this problem because the version of `tracing-core` was too high, we had to fix the version of `tracing-core` to `0.1.26`.
https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/issues/11691

Solution:
edit `/node/Cargo.toml`

```rust
......

[dependencies]
tracing-core = "=0.1.26"

......
```